# Make animation to a specific object from a lot of with this selector in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I make a javascript function that when I click to a specific image (the ids are different) then the image will disappear? I make a JS function but isn't working. **The images ara loaded from a post request to a database and there is a delay before showing to the dom !!!**

```js
var matches = document.querySelectorAll("img");

matches.forEach((this) => {
  this.addEventListener("click", () => {
    this.className("hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="keys">
  <img src="images\Clothing\1.png" style="width:10%; padding:0.1em; margin:0.5em" class="zoom" id="img0"><img src="images\Clothing\2.png" style="width:10%; padding:0.1em; margin:0.5em" class="zoom" id="img1"><img src="images\Clothing\3.png" style="width:10%; padding:0.1em; margin:0.5em"
    class="zoom" id="img2"><img src="images\Clothing\4.png" style="width:10%; padding:0.1em; margin:0.5em" class="zoom" id="img3">
  <img src="images\Vegetables\4.png" style="width:10%; padding:0.1em; margin:0.5em" class="zoom" id="img43"><img src="images\Vegetables\5.png" style="width:10%; padding:0.1em; margin:0.5em" class="zoom" id="img44">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of issues here. Firstly `this` is a reserved keyword. You cannot use it as a function argument name. Secondly, `this` within the inner arrow function will refer to the outer scope due to lexical binding in arrow functions. For it to reference the `img` element which was clicked you need to use an anonymous function. Lastly there is no `classname` property of an element. You can use `classList.add()` instead. Try this:

```js
var matches = document.querySelectorAll("img");
matches.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.add("hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#keys img.zoom {
  width: 10%;
  padding: 0.1em;
  margin: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="keys">
  <img src="images\Clothing\1.png" class="zoom" id="img0">
  <img src="images\Clothing\2.png" class="zoom" id="img1">
  <img src="images\Clothing\3.png" class="zoom" id="img2">
  <img src="images\Clothing\4.png" class="zoom" id="img3">
  <img src="images\Vegetables\4.png" class="zoom" id="img43">
  <img src="images\Vegetables\5.png" class="zoom" id="img44">
</div>
```

As an aside, you should remove the inline `style` attribute as it's not good practice. You should apply styling via external stylesheets. As you've already got a class on the `img` elements this can be targeted directly.

*- Update -*

> The images are loaded from a POST request to a database and there is a delay before showing to the DOM

In this case you need to bind the event handlers above *after* the POST request completes.

Alternatively, as you've tagged jQuery in the question, you could use it to simply set up a single delegated event handler:

The equivalent logic in jQuery would be:

```
$(document).on('click', 'img.zoom', function() {
  $(this).addClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: The images ara loaded from a post request to a database and there is a delay before showing to the dom, so I think this is a problem because isn't working.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest using a delegated event handler. I've updated the answer to show you how

Comment: As I mentioned, because you're loading the elements through AJAX you need to attach the event handlers *after* that call completes. As such either use the jQuery delegated handler, or move the plain JS code to within the `xhr.onreadystatechange` function

Comment: No problem,  glad to help

Comment: The [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) property.

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll()` returns the `NodeList` objects which is collections of nodes,
We can use `for` loop for iterating over this node list but not `for...in` or `for..each`
as per Mozilla documentation 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

> Don't use for...in or for each...in to enumerate the items in NodeLists, since they will also enumerate its length and item properties and cause errors if your script assumes it only has to deal with element objects. Also, for..in is not guaranteed to visit the properties in any particular order.

So according to this following code can be helpful to you

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var matches = document.querySelectorAll("img");
  console.log("matches ", matches);
  for (let i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    matches[i].addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      matches[i].classList.add("hidden");
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: The OP isn't using a `for/in` loop here. Calling `forEach()` on a NodeList is perfectly valid, although not supported in some outdated legacy browsers. In other words, IE.

Comment: The images are loaded at real time from a javascript function with xhr send post message soo will be a problem because I run your code and nothing happend

Answer (score 0):

When using arrow functions there's no `this` rebinding, so your inner function `this` refers to the `window`. The same is true of the outer function, since `this` is a reserved word, you cannot assign it in this way, so you have to use another name.

To recover the `click` target you can use the [event data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

If the images are loaded asyncronously, when you set up the listeners the elements won't exist, so what you can do is delegate to other existing element and check if the `target` [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) the desired selector.

```js
document.getElementById("keys").addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (e.target.matches("img")) {
    e.target.className = "hidden";
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="keys">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" style="width:10%; padding:0.1em; margin:0.5em" class="zoom" id="img43">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300" style="width:10%; padding:0.1em; margin:0.5em" class="zoom" id="img44">
</div>
```

Comment: The images are loaded at real time from a javascript function with xhr send post message soo will be a problem because I run your code and nothing happend

Comment: @AntriaPanayiotou Try the ammended version.

Comment: @AntriaPanayiotou I can't find that code. Change function starting in line 69 in `validation2.js` with this code. It works for me when executed in the console and then calling `sendGETDataToServer()`.